# File version 0.0.0.0 in Windows Explorer file properties 'Details' tab of .exe compiled with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In Visual Studio 2010 if my AssemblyInfo.cs contained these lines (where "2010.1.2.3.4" would actually be the current year.month.day.hour.minute):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2010.1.2.3.4")]
```

I could then look at the file properties in Windows Explorer of the resultant .exe and the details tab would show:

```
File version 2010.1.2.3
Product version 2010.1.2.3.4
```

However, in Visual Studio 2017 with the exact same AssemblyInfo.cs the resultant .exe file properties details tab shows:

```
File version 0.0.0.0
Product version 2010.1.2.3.4
```

There appear to be many *similar* postings on SO, but I can't find any *exact* matches that explain why this is happening or how to fix it so that "File version" displays as 2010.1.2.3 when building the .exe with VS2017 just like it did when building the .exe with VS2010.

Comment: I tried creating a console app in VS2017 .NET 4.7.2 and once i compiled what I see in Widows Explorer is AssemblyFileVersion is used for both File Version and Product Version

Comment: Have you set these values in the properties of which project in the solution?

Comment: @Darkonekt I targeted both 4.0 and 4.6.1 and both produce the same result.  I don't have 4.7.2 as an option, which I assume is because I don't have it installed.  Though I cna't imagine that this would be fixed for me if I target 4.7.2.  Very weird that you are seeing the behavior that I saw in VS2010.  Makes me wonder if something got carried over improperly from the project upgrade to 2017.  I'll see what happens if I create a brand new project.

Comment: @Jimi the values are set in the AssemblyInfo.cs file in the project.  If you look at the properties of the project in VS, the same values appear there too.

Comment: I tried creating new console app using 4.6.1 and I got AssemblyFileVersion shown on both File Version and Product Version

Comment: If the Explorer details pane you usually see the Product version, equal to the file version. I don't remember this failing. Try to clean the Solution and rebuild it. See that you actually look at the executable in the current build mode :). Also, that you don't have warnings while rebuilding the solution.

Comment: I can confirm that when I create a brand new project/solution the numbers match.  The issue only exists in my solution that was upgraded from 2010 to 2017.  Clean solution and rebuild did not solve the issue, unfortunately.  But at least we now know the issue is in my solution/project.  I will continue looking there to see if I can find where the problem is.  There are no warnings during build/rebuild.  And yes I am looking at the correct executable. Thanks.

Comment: Well I painstakingly created a new project and copied all of the code and resources etc one by one very carefully, making sure to never copy any settings files etc.  Eventually when I finally got the new project to build, the same issue exists!

Comment: See that you don't have [AssemblyVersionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute) (or some of its friends) somewhere in your code. I would have asked you whether you had pre-build events set, but since you built another solution/project from scratch...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have AssemblyVersionAttribute anywhere.  I had actually already scanned the entire code for 'assembly' and 'version', and now I just specifically also looked for 'assemblyversion' and 'assemblyversionattribute' without finding anything.  This is insane.

Comment: Also FWIW I do actually have a pre-build event, but all that does is run a script that modifies my AssemblyInfo.cs to update the line [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2010.1.2.3.4")] with the current date.  If I comment that line out altogether so that the file only contains the [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")], then both the  'File version' and 'Product version' details display '1.0.1234.12345'.  However, as soon as I add back the line [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2010.1.2.3.4")], I'm back to where I was before with 0.0.0.0 for File version, and 2010.1.2.3.4 for Product version.  :(

Comment: I can reproduce your issue using VS2013 and VS2017.  In VS2017, it appears as though the issue is with the use of 5 version number components versus the expected 4 version number components (major version number, minor version number, build number, and revision number). Using a _non-standard_ version format is [documented as causing unpredictable explorer property results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.0#remarks).

Comment: @TnTinMn Amazing!  I shortened it to 4 components and the problem disappeared.  Wow.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @TnTinMn it turns out that the issue was with including 5 component numbers in AssemblyFileVersion instead of the expected/typical 4, which produced unreliable results, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.0#remarks):

> The file version is normally a string of four numbers, separated by
>   periods, reflecting the major version number, minor version number,
>   build number, and revision number; for example, "1.0.4309.00". If
>   version is not in this format, a compiler warning occurs, and the
>   results displayed in the file properties dialog are unpredictable.
>   Wildcards are not supported.

After updating the AssemblyInfo.cs AssemblyFileVersion to only contain 4 component numbers, the problem disappeared.